How do I webscrape filtered content from a website
I want to filter the Innovfest x Elevating Founders (Startup/Scaleup) category and scrape all the exhibitor names and booth number from here: https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/
When I attempt to add the filter, I get an error
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 36
     34 # Locate and click the dropdown to reveal the checkboxes
     35 dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-hook='filter-dropdown']")))
---> 36 dropdown.click()
     37 time.sleep(2)  # Allow the dropdown to open
     39 # Get all the filter checkboxes

File c:\Users\twbsguser009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:94, in WebElement.click(self)
     92 def click(self) -> None:
     93     """Clicks the element."""
---> 94     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

File c:\Users\twbsguser009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:395, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    393     params = {}
    394 params["id"] = self._id
--> 395 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File c:\Users\twbsguser009\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:347, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    345 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    346 if response:
--> 347     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    348     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    349     return response
...
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A3483592]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A3472F9F]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF26B1257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF27FEAA48+40]

Code
# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Initialize WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/")

# Wait for the iframe to load and switch to it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "IframeModule_iframe__JCvXg")))

# Scroll to the bottom of the page to ensure all elements are loaded
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)  # Allow some time for the page to load new content

# Scroll until the last specific element is found
match = False
while not match:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)  # Allow some time for the page to load new content
    last_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Singapore Centre for Social Enterprise, raiSE Ltd']")
    if len(last_element) >= 1:
        match = True

# Locate and click the dropdown to reveal the checkboxes
dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-hook='filter-dropdown']")))
dropdown.click()
time.sleep(2)  # Allow the dropdown to open

# Get all the filter checkboxes
checkboxes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(@data-hook, 'exhibitor-filter')]")

exhibitor_names = []

# Loop through each checkbox to apply the filter and gather names
for checkbox in checkboxes:
    # Check the checkbox
    checkbox.click()
    time.sleep(2)  # Allow some time for the filter to apply

    # Get the filtered company names
    filtered_names = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sc-a13c392f-0 sc-85df61db-4 feepZZ eErKol']")))
    logger.info(f"No. of sponsors and exhibitors after applying filter= {len(filtered_names)}")
    
    # Append the names to the list
    for name in filtered_names:
        exhibitor_names.append(name.text)

    # Uncheck the checkbox to reset the filter
    checkbox.click()
    time.sleep(2)  # Allow some time for the filter to reset

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

# Print or log all collected exhibitor names
logger.info(f"Total exhibitors collected: {len(exhibitor_names)}")
for name in exhibitor_names:
    print(name)

This is what I have currently. How do I make it such that it scrapes only the filtered exhibitors? Thank you in advance

Where is your code that attempts to apply a filter?

@JeffC I've added my attempt at applying a filter.

Your code in the question is a mess... you have 2 different code blocks, etc. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

I've removed a block of code..hope that it is better

selenium gives references to objects in browser memory, when you click objects then browser may remove objects or move them to different place and references are updateded - and next click may try to access object which doesn't exists. It may need to search all object again in every loop.

I suggest to mimic the Rest API to get the exhibitor info:
import requests

api_url = "https://attend.informatechevents.virtual.informatech.com/api/graphql"

payload = [
    {
        "extensions": {
            "persistedQuery": {
                "sha256Hash": "a717703fa8924575e04c9968ef2f441781e9cb8e2d5ca62d9ca9742bd04eac93",
                "version": 1,
            }
        },
        "operationName": "EventExhibitorListViewConnectionQuery",
        "variables": {
            "eventId": "RXZlbnRfMTc5MDkyMQ==",  # Event_1790921
            "selectedFilters": [
                {
                    "mustEventFiltersIn": [
                        {
                            "filterId": "RmllbGREZWZpbml0aW9uXzMwNTU5NA==",  # FieldDefinition_305594
                            "values": [
                                "RmllbGRWYWx1ZV8yMzI1MDQ5Mg==",  # FieldValue_23250492 "InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Silver Sponsors"
                                "RmllbGRWYWx1ZV8yMzYxMjEzNA==",  # FieldValue_23612134 "InnovFest x Elevating Founders Knowledge Partner"
                                "RmllbGRWYWx1ZV8yMzI1MDQ5Ng==",  # FieldValue_23250496 "InnovFest x Elevating Founders Institutes of Higher Learning"
                                "RmllbGRWYWx1ZV8yMzI1MDQ5NQ==",  # FieldValue_23250495 "InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Bronze Sponsors"
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "viewId": "RXZlbnRWaWV3Xzc2MDczMA==",  # EventView_760730
            "withEvent": True,
        },
    }
]

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

# print(data)

for e in data[0]["data"]["view"]["exhibitors"]["nodes"]:
    print(e["name"])
    print(e["type"])
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:
Republic Polytechnic
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Institutes of Higher Learning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Singapore University of Social Sciences
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Institutes of Higher Learning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Temasek Polytechnic
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Institutes of Higher Learning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Femtech
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Knowledge Partner
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IIPCC
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Knowledge Partner
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPOS
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Knowledge Partner
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Singapore Centre for Social Enterprise, raiSE Ltd
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Knowledge Partner
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds, P.C.
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Silver Sponsors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Krislab, SIA Digital Innovation Lab
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Silver Sponsors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Marks & Clerk Singapore LLP
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Silver Sponsors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Singapore Science Park Limited
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Silver Sponsors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHINA SINDA IP
InnovFest x Elevating Founders Asia Bronze Sponsors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


I only get 12 when I should be getting more. Is it because the website is dynamic? How do I deal with it in this case?

@user22279494 when I scroll page in browser and check requests (in tab Network in DevTools) then I see object endCursor in response, and in other requests - maybe you have to get this value from one request and use it in next request to get next results. And response will give new endCursor to get next results.

@user22279494 see data[0]["data"]["view"]['exhibitors']['pageInfo'] - it has fields endCursor and hasNextPage. And if hasNextPage is True then probably you may need to add endCursor in "variables" to get next page with data.
